# Trying to subclass UIImage but image is not being displayed in the image view

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimage

I am trying to subclass UIImage so I can include a special title and other information I need for each image. Below is my .m :

```
#import "Sticker.h"

@implementation Sticker



//custom init
-(instancetype)initWithTitle: (NSString *)title neededCount: (int)neededCount specialMesage: (NSString *)specialMesage andFilename: (NSString *)path {

    self = [super initWithContentsOfFile:path];

    if(self) {

        self.title=title;
        self.neededCount=neededCount;
        self.specialMessage=specialMessage;


    }

    return self;



}
```

I have an empty view controller with a single UIImageView and I am trying to create a new sticker object and use the image in the UIImageView. Code:

```
Sticker *sticker = [[Sticker alloc] initWithTitle:@"crazy clown" neededCount:50 specialMessage:@"stackoverflow" andFilename:@"clown"];
    self.imageView.image=sticker;
    self.imageView.hidden=NO;
```

For some reason the image isn't showing and there are no error messages. "clown" is a pdf image in Images.xcassets. Can anyone give me some pointers to why this isn't working please?

Answer (score 0):

You should not subclass UIImage for this try to create a class with a UIImage property instead.

```
@interface Sticker : NSObject
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *title;
@property (assign, nonatomic) int neededCount;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *specialMessage;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *image;

-(instancetype)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title neededCount:(int)neededCount specialMesage:(NSString *)specialMessage filename:(NSString *)name;

@end

@implementation Sticker

-(instancetype)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title neededCount:(int)neededCount specialMesage:(NSString *)specialMessage filename:(NSString *)name {
    if(self = [super init]) {
        self.title = title;
        self.neededCount = neededCount;
        self.specialMessage = specialMessage;
        self.image = [UIImage imageNamed:name];
    }
    return self;
}

@end

Sticker *sticker = [[Sticker alloc] initWithTitle:@"crazy clown" neededCount:50 specialMessage:@"stackoverflow" filename:@"clown"];
self.imageView.image = sticker.image;
```

Anyway `initWithContentsOfFile` needs a complete path not just the filename.

Comment: Why is it bad to subclass UIImage?

Comment: It is not always bad but in this case given that a UIImage is just a pixel collection ask yourself, why a UIImage should know title, specialMessage and neededCount? I do not see valid reasons to add these informations in a UIImage.

Answer (score -1):

Subclassing UIImage is a bit funky. But it can be done

```
class PlaceHolderIcon: UIImage {

    override init() {
        let image = UIImage(named: "image-name")!
        super.init(cgImage: image.cgImage!, scale: UIScreen.main.scale, orientation: .up)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    required convenience init(imageLiteralResourceName name: String) {
        fatalError("init(imageLiteralResourceName:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```